# Why does this expression parser scale so bad in the number of (some?) rules?

Tags: performance, parsing, time-complexity, idris, parser-combinators

I'm trying to use Idris 2's `Text.Parser` library to parse a pre-tokenized byte stream. I wrote the following utility function in the style of [Parsec's expression parser](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.14.0/docs/Text-Parsec-Expr.html):

```
module Text.Parser.Expression

import Text.Parser

public export
data Assoc
   = AssocNone
   | AssocLeft
   | AssocRight

public export
data Op state k a
  = Prefix (Grammar state k True (a -> a))
  | Infix (Grammar state k True (a -> a -> a)) Assoc

public export
OpTable : Type -> Type -> Type -> Type
OpTable state k a = List (List (Op state k a))

public export
expressionParser :
  OpTable state k a ->
  Grammar state k True a ->
  Grammar state k True a
expressionParser table term = foldl level term table
  where
    level : Grammar state k True a -> List (Op state k a) -> Grammar state k True a
    level factor ops = choiceMap toP ops <|> factor
      where
        toP : Op state k a -> Grammar state k True a
        toP (Infix op AssocNone) = do
          x <- factor
          f <- op
          y <- factor
          pure $ f x y
        toP (Infix op AssocLeft) = do
          x <- factor
          fs <- some (flip <$> op <*> factor)
          pure $ foldl (flip ($)) x fs
        toP (Infix op AssocRight) = do
          fs <- some (factor >>= \x => op <*> pure x)
          y <- factor
          pure $ foldr ($) y fs
        toP (Prefix op) = op <*> factor
```

For certain inputs, this seems to scale really badly with the number of operator definitions. Here's a cut-down example:

```
public export
Number : Type
Number = Double

public export
data Fun
  = IntFun
  | Rnd

public export
data BinOp
   = Eq
   | NEq
   | LT
   | LE
   | GT
   | GE
   | Plus
   | Minus
   | Mul
   | And
   | Or

public export
data Expr
  = NumLitE Number
  | Bin BinOp Expr Expr
  | FunE Fun (List1 Expr)

public export
Show Fun where
  show IntFun = "INT"
  show Rnd = "RND"

public export
Show BinOp where
  show Eq = "="
  show NEq = "<>"
  show LT = "<"
  show LE = "<="
  show GT = ">"
  show GE = ">="
  show Plus = "+"
  show Minus = "-"
  show Mul = "*"
  show And = "AND"
  show Or = "OR"

public export
Show Expr where
  show (NumLitE n) = show n
  show (Bin op x y) = unwords [show x, show op, show y]
  show (FunE f args) = show f ++ "(" ++ show args ++ ")"

bits8 : Bits8 -> Grammar state Bits8 True ()
bits8 x = terminal ("Byte " ++ show x) $ \x' => if x == x' then Just () else Nothing

lexeme : {c : Bool} -> Grammar state Bits8 c a -> Grammar state Bits8 c a
lexeme p = afterMany (bits8 0x20) p

comma : Grammar state Bits8 True ()
comma = lexeme $ bits8 0x2c

parens : {c : Bool} -> Grammar state Bits8 c a -> Grammar state Bits8 True a
parens = between (lexeme $ bits8 0x28) (lexeme $ bits8 0x29)

digit : Grammar state Bits8 True Bits8
digit = terminal "digit" $ \x =>
  toMaybe (0x30 <= x && x <= 0x39) x

digitLit : (Num a) => Grammar state Bits8 True a
digitLit = fromInteger . cast . (\x => x - 0x30) <$> digit

numLit : (Num a, Neg a) => Grammar state Bits8 True a
numLit {a} = fromDigits <$> lexeme sign <*> lexeme (some digitLit)
  where
    fromDigits : Bool -> List1 a -> a
    fromDigits neg =
      (if neg then negate else id) .
      foldl (\x => \y => x * 10 + y) (the a 0)

    sign : Grammar state Bits8 False Bool
    sign = option False $ True <$ bits8 0xab

expr : Grammar state Bits8 True Expr
expr = expressionParser table term <|> fail "expression"
  where
    table : List (List (Op state Bits8 Expr))
    table =
      [ [ Infix (lexeme $ Bin Mul <$ bits8 0xac) AssocLeft
        ]
      , [ Infix (lexeme $ Bin Plus  <$ bits8 0xaa) AssocLeft
        , Infix (lexeme $ Bin Minus <$ bits8 0xab) AssocLeft
        ]
      , -- This next group is the one I will keep shrinking
        [ Infix (lexeme $ Bin Eq  <$ bits8 0xb2) AssocNone
        , Infix (lexeme $ Bin NEq <$ (bits8 0xb3 *> bits8 0xb1)) AssocNone
        , Infix (lexeme $ Bin GE  <$ (bits8 0xb1 *> bits8 0xb2)) AssocNone
        , Infix (lexeme $ Bin GT  <$ bits8 0xb1) AssocNone
        , Infix (lexeme $ Bin LE  <$ (bits8 0xb3 *> bits8 0xb2)) AssocNone
        , Infix (lexeme $ Bin LT  <$ bits8 0xb3) AssocNone
        ]
      , [ Infix (lexeme $ Bin And <$ bits8 0xaf) AssocLeft
        , Infix (lexeme $ Bin Or  <$ bits8 0xb0) AssocLeft
        ]
      ]

    fun : Grammar state Bits8 True Fun
    fun = lexeme $ choice
      [ IntFun  <$ bits8 0xb5
      , Rnd     <$ bits8 0xbb
      ]

    term : Grammar state Bits8 True Expr
    term =
          NumLitE <$> numLit
      <|> FunE <$> fun <*> parens (sepBy1 comma expr)
      <|> parens expr
```

For measurement, I have tried parsing `[181,40,40,187,40,49,41,172,51,41,170,49,41]` while removing the parsing rules for `Eq`, `NEq`, ..., `Lt`. Here is the user time of parsing the above list of bytes with the number of rules not commented out in that parsing rule group:

| n | usr (seconds) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.41 |
| 2 | 1.56 |
| 3 | 4.67 |
| 4 | 13.92 |
| 5 | 25.71 |
| 6 | 45.92 |

What is going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by [copying more of Parsec's design](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris2/blob/ba180706d607945d8b419301f4362471d97a306a/libs/contrib/Text/Parser/Expression.idr). As can be seen at that link, the important idea is to parse a leading term just once, and then parse a chain of associative operators and operands following it. This avoids repeated re-parsing of higher-precedence terms, which is what's causing the slowdown in the code in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Not an answer, but a viable workaround is merging all comparison operators into a single parser:

```
  cmp : Grammar state Bits8 True BinOp
  cmp = choice
    [ Eq  <$ bits8 0xb2
    , NEq <$ bits8 0xb3 <* bits8 0xb1
    , GE  <$ bits8 0xb1 <* bits8 0xb2
    , GT  <$ bits8 0xb1
    , LE  <$ bits8 0xb3 <* bits8 0xb2
    , LT  <$ bits8 0xb3
    ]

  table : List (List (Op state Bits8 Expr))
  table =
    [ [ Infix (lexeme $ Bin Mul <$ bits8 0xac) AssocLeft
      ]
    , [ Infix (lexeme $ Bin Plus <$ bits8 0xaa) AssocLeft
      , Infix (lexeme $ Bin Minus <$ bits8 0xab) AssocLeft
      ]
    , [ Infix (Bin <$> lexeme cmp) AssocNone ]
    , [ Infix (lexeme $ Bin And <$ bits8 0xaf) AssocLeft
      , Infix (lexeme $ Bin Or <$ bits8 0xb0) AssocLeft
      ]
    ]
```

This suggests a more principled improvement which is to collect all non-associative operators per precedence level in `expressionParser` itself and do this transformation.